# sh source permission denied trying to call another script

Tags: sh

Can you make a `sh` script call another script? (Apparently not.)

```
rwb@calleva:~/source$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr--r-- 1 rwb rwb 50 Oct 22 03:38 caller.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 rwb rwb 30 Oct 22 03:36 sourced.sh
rwb@calleva:~/source$ cat sourced.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "sourced.sh"

rwb@calleva:~/source$ ./sourced.sh
sourced.sh
rwb@calleva:~/source$ cat caller.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "caller.sh"

source ./sourced.sh

rwb@calleva:~/source$ ./caller.sh
caller.sh
./caller.sh: 5: source: Permission denied
rwb@calleva:~/source$
```

Comment: Try `.` instead of `source`. AFAIK, `source` is not POSIX and may not be available in some shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is an alternative name for the `.` builtin, but only in some shells. [`.` is in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot), it's portable; `source` is not.

When writing code for `sh`, one should only use portable shell features. The basic point of writing code for `sh` is making it work in *any* implementation of `sh`. In general `sh` may be a symlink to `bash`, `dash` or some other shell. Even if this shell itself supports `source`, it may or may not support it when called as `sh`. And even if this shell itself supports `source` when called as `sh`, it's still a bad practice to write non-portable code when you are going to make `sh` interpret the code.

Maybe your `/bin/sh` does not support `source`; if so, it will treat `source` in `source ./sourced.sh` like any other not-a-keyword-and-not-a-builtin. Then maybe there is an executable file called `source` in some directory in your `$PATH`; if so, the shell will try to run it. Then maybe the mode of the file does not allow you to run it; if so, the error message will be `source: Permission denied`.

A solution is to use `.` instead of `source`. Any `sh` should understand `.` in the way you expected your `sh` to understand `source`.

Having `source` as an executable file is (in my opinion) uncommon. The above hypothesis, while plausible, may *or may not* be what happens in your particular case. Even if the solution does not (or does not fully) solve your particular case, using `.` instead of `source` in shell code *for `sh`* is still the Right Thing.